# Python - Running just a single line of code, and not the rest of the Multiple lines in the Script

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-idle

In - Python, inside the the IDLE, in the File Editor Window,

How do you run just a selected single line of code in the script, without having the rest of the lines of the program being runned ?

Answer (score 15):

You'll have to run your line of code form command line:

With the -c (command) argument (assuming your file is named foo.py):

```
$ python -c 'import foo; print foo.hello()'
```

Comment: I have tried inputting what typed above in the file editor window.  but what gets produced in the Shell, is $ python -c          .  My file name is Traffic Calculation.py  ,   here is the line i just want to run, print('Hi John, what road are you travelling for work today ?')   so how this be written ?

Comment: You need to input this in the shell comnand line not in editor

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IdleX extension (https://github.com/serwy/idlex): it adds the ability to run any selected text by pressing F9 (among other things that I haven't tested yet).

Answer (score 0):

You can select and copy a single statement in an Idle editor (or anywhere else, for that matter), switch to the Idle Shell, and paste on the line with the >>> prompt as the bottom.  (You can hit  to get a clean prompt.) Then hit return just as it you had entered into the shell directly.  This works for multiline statements. Being able to do this with a menu selection, hotkey, or right-click selection is on my todo list, as you are not the first to ask about this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what we call **"debugger"** should be fulfilled your requirement. Many IDEs are provided "debugger tools" including `IDLE`. To use a debugger tool you can just simply

1. add break lines (any lines of code you want a program to stop while program is running),
2. explore your variables (when program is stop you can print out values  of your variables at that time)
3. Click/type `step` to go to the next breakpoint.

This is just a roughly procedure that should be fit to your requirement.

see more: [debug](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~paulp/CS115F11/notes/debug/debug.html)