# Is there a way to start the python intrepeter so i can python print('hello world') without hitting enter first?

Tags: python

Because i would like to execute python scripts from my package.json like so

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "p": "python exec(compile(unhexlify(hex).decode(), '', 'exec'))"
    }
}
```

Is there any argument we can give to python to make this possible?

Comment: What is "package.json"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Running just a single line of code, and not the rest of the Multiple lines in the Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503362/python-running-just-a-single-line-of-code-and-not-the-rest-of-the-multiple-li)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-c` argument:

```
$ python3 -c 'print("hello world")'
hello world
```